# Is there a journal that publishes slides together with the text?

Tags: publications, journals, supporting-information

*I mainly refer to applied mathematics when describing my experience*

Often I find that it is easier to grasp a concept from the author's slides than from the description in a paper. When one has to summarize their findings for a talk, they often end up with an exposition that gives a clearer understanding of the "big picture" and the nontrivial details. It is easier to separate what is important and what is not. If someone really needs more detail and rigour, they can check the paper, but I think that 90% of the readership would get more from the slides than from the paper.

Of course a real paper is still necessary, to provide details to the interested reader and to testify that the details work indeed (and the referees can certify it).

However, slides are typically difficult to find. Some scientists self-archive (a subset of) their slides on their personal web pages; some others are hidden in conference sites. No database such as Scopus indexes them. It is often tricky to match up a paper and its slides.

So, my question is the following.

---

Is there any journal that publishes slides together with their papers? Or slides only? Or, more generally, that tries to experiment and consider similar less formal media for presenting real science?

---

Comment: (Moving previous answer to a comment as suggested by another user.)
I asked the same question on MathOverflow: Is there an arXiv for Beamer presentations of scientific work?

Someone suggested I look on this forum, and then I found the question was already asked.

Basically I'm also curious if there's a reputable journal that publishes the slides from research presentations. If there isn't I think that we should have one. It could give a way to better publicize our work.

Comment: @LukeOeding Could you please link to the MO question, for reference?

Comment: Yeah, sorry the link didn't automatically come with the copy-paste. I'm not able to edit the comment for some reason, so here's the link: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178702/is-there-an-arxiv-for-beamer-presentations-of-scientific-work

Comment: @LukeOeding It works as the SE developers intended: unlike answers, comments can be edited only for 5 minutes or so after one posts them (and they have no saved history). And, by the way, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I **don't know of any such journal**.  The closest I've come to this is that often **after I've listened to a talk, I've asked the speaker for his slides**.  I can't recall ever being turned down.  Alternatively, if you can't attend a talk, you might still ask the speaker for his/her slides.  This request will likely be a bit more successful in person, but even via email it can't hurt to try.

Comment: I post my slides on my personal website. That way people can take a look on their own time if they want.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know about any such journal. But one idea could be to archive your papers on a pre-print server, such as arXiv and always append your slides as an appendix.

Answer (score 3):

All the Nature journals and Science make their figures available as PPT slides with the captions available as comments, presumably to facilitate their use in journal clubs. Tinkering with something such as TikZ for a bit will tell you that it's not trivial to productively annotate equations.

Perhaps, and I don't say this glibly, you would deepen your understanding of difficult papers by making the slides you wish you had. It helped me.

Comment: Interesting. Do you know what the copyright terms on the figures are?

Comment: I believe for "academic use online". That is, you can't claim it as your own and unless you're just making notes for yourself put a citation at the bottom of the slide.

Comment: Journals are generally __much more__ protective about copyrights. Every publisher has a link their journals page where re-use of figures etc can be requested through a form. E.g. in the case of Nature every article has a "rights and permission" link, which leads you a copyright clearance service where you can ask permissions for use __even if you are the author yourself__.

Answer (score 1):

Elsevier journals now offer [AudioSlides](http://www.elsevier.com/about/content-innovation/audioslides-author-presentations-for-journal-articles),

> short, webcast-style presentations that are shown next to the online article on ScienceDirect. This format gives authors the opportunity to present their research in their own words, helping readers to quickly understand what a paper is about and appreciate its relevance.

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

With many, perhaps most)  journals it is possible to add materials,often referred to as *Supplementary Material* or *Supporting Information* or something similar. This can be word files, powerpoint files, excel files (or equivalents), media files (sound, movies, animations) containing material that support the article but cannot be accommodated within the usual journal format.

I am, however, not sure if a slide presentation of the article material would be permitted since it would not necessarily add anything new but rather be a simplification of the article content.